# How to smoothly develop a C lib for C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, c, dll

I am developing a complex library in C++ and i plan on having a C interface so others can load up the DLL and easily access the lib. I haven't tried writing code in C# that access C code. I did a quick google and found code that uses a lot of attributes.

What can I do to keep my interface simple enough to not cause a headache trying to keep .NET in sync with it? Is there some kind of header generation tool i may use? Do i only use simple POD structs? I'm unsure how i should handle types as they are passed around as pointers. I am also thinking maybe i should avoid using anything that is a not an int/string or array.

I am developing it using MSVC but mostly using it with GCC. I know i should use the calling convention __stdcall. Beyond what i said i am totally clueless. I actually dont know how to load the DLL into .NET.

What can i do to ensure everything works correctly when writing my C lib and getting it to run with .NET?

Comment: You don't have to use `__stdcall`. You can P/Invoke just fine with `__cdecl` if you prefer that.

Answer (score 2):

Consider putting together a COM interface. Consuming COM from .NET is marginally easier than P/Invoke; at least you won't have to spell out prototypes for all functions in C#, the COM typelib importer will do that for you.